Do I need a GFCI sticker when grounded by box
I have replaced a 3-prong bathroom outlet with GFCI. The metal box does not have any ground wire in it, so I just connected the hot and neutral wires. I was expecting the outlet tester to indicate the outlet is ungrounded, but it says everything is ok so I assume the box itself is providing the ground.
In this circumstance, do I need to use the "No Equipment Grounding" sticker?

Does the box have wires coming out of a tube/pipe or a cable?  If a tube(conduit) that is metal, that will be a ground path back to the panel.

something wrong here a 3-prong bathroom outlet should have a ground

@DIY75, It does have a ground. The ground is run through the metal box. Just because there is no ground wire doesn't mean there is no ground.

Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

@RMDman what is the 3d prong for, how is it connected

@DIY75   Metal conduit, if OP has one, is a ground path also.  Most metal conduit systems do not use ground wires, except from the box to outlet/switch if needed.  The better devices are grounded through the mounting screws.

@DIY75, the 3rd prong is still grounded through contacts internally in the outlet.

@MikeWaters only if you are sufficently inexperienced to miss the obvious point that Mark is talking about connecting them to the appropriate hot and neutral terminals on the GFCI outlet, which is obvious from context, since "the breaker tripped immediately" is not in this question, and "the outlet tester indicates that everything is OK" is.

A good test for a good ground is using a multi-tester between hot/live wire and the box.  It should read local voltage, in the US ~120v.  Much difference in local voltage or 0v means a bad ground connection.

Peripheral to question but important:  A GFCI does not NEED a ground to work correctly. || In a bathroom having a ground avai;lable INCREASES the hazard.  In NZ (where I am) a normal outlet is illegal in a bathroom. I am NOT saying that you should disobey local rules, but noting that regardless of the rules/code/ ... ANY ground adds to the hazard level when a GFCI is used.

@RussellMcMahon Maybe NZ is different. With a US configuration, I don't see how any ground adds to the hazard level when a GFCI is used. If the ground gets current that was "from" the hot, that should have gone to neutral, GFCI will trip. If it gets static, surge protector surge current, etc. then it works as a simple ground. And if current were to go through a wet person to physical ground (e.g., plumbing pipes or wet floor) then GFCI would trip the same whether or not there is a ground on the receptacle because nothing would be flowing through to that ground.

@Mark does the GF CI outlet trip when the tester button is pressed? This is the most important question.

@tomnexus In some ways yes, but in some ways no. While I highly doubt it in this particular situation, it is possible to wire neutral and ground together in the box (totally wrong, but it happens...) and then connect the GFCI/receptacle. If you do that then a 3-light tester will show good, the GFCI internal TEST will show good. A 3-light tester with a GFCI test function may show good. So GFCI would be "covered", but the actual ground would not function properly.

@DIY75 when a cable comes into a steel box, it is a code REQUIREMENT that the cable ground go to the metal box "first" i.e. as a priority. The box must remain grounded even if the outlet etc. is removed.   Once the box is grounded, switches pick up ground automagically via the mounting screws, as do receps labeled "Self-Grounding" including most GFCIs.  Or simply by hard flush clean metal contact metal receptacle yoke to box flange.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes sort of / no sort of / Yes more than no :-). A GFCI tripping to ground will USUALLY not hurt you. In VERY borderline cases it may. This is unusual/unlikely/extreme outlier.  Try not to be that person :-(. I'm not , based on the too many shocks I've had in my 73 years. If there is NO ground you cannot get a live to ground shock. If the wiring provides one you can. || Tripping a GFCI gives you a solid but extremely brief shock - I tried it long ago on the back of a hand to see.  || But, yes, most of the time the extra ground is not a hazartd.

TL;DR No
Ground can be provided to a receptacle in four different ways:

Plastic box - ground wire to screw on receptacle
Metal box - ground wire to screw on receptacle - but note that in this case the ground wire should actually go to the box first and then to the receptacle
Metal box - metal conduit securely fastened to the box and receptacle automagically gets grounded
Metal box - ground wire to metal box and receptacle automagically gets grounded

This is #9 on my list of reasons metal boxes are better.
Presumably you have one of the last two possibilities. If you see a ground wire connected inside the box then you have # 4. If you don't see a ground wire then you either have # 4 or you have # 3 but with the ground wire connected on the outside of the box. That last possibility is not ideal because it can't be easily verified that it is a secure connection, but it does work.
Any of these will result in a properly grounded receptacle and, therefore no need for (and in fact it would be wrong) a "not grounded" label.
Keep in mind that not all receptacles will automagically work this way. Your typical 77 cent receptacle (hard to believe that anything even close to reliable can be sold retail at that price, but that's mass production for you) won't do it. But spend around $2 or $3 for a "commercial grade" receptacle and you will get:

Grounding via the yoke - often called "self-grounding". The instructions should make it very clear.
Screw-to-clamp or similar method of using straight wires (much easier than getting a hook "just right") that is much more secure than "backstab" connections.
Generally better construction in many other ways.

Most, if not all, GFCI/receptacles have these features. Check your GFCI/receptacle instructions and it should make it clear whether it has "self-grounding" or not. If it does, you're all set.
There is still the big question of: What was the previous situation?

replaced a 3-prong bathroom outlet

should mean there was a proper ground previously. In fact, one of the main reasons for "GFCI with no ground" is specifically to replace a 2-prong receptacle witha  3-prong receptacle when ground is simply not available. (It makes sense to replace with GFCI in a bathroom whether starting with 2-prong or 3-prong because of the safety benefits of GFCI in wet areas.) So unless the previous 3-prong receptacle was installed improperly (e.g., ground connected to neutral to give the appearance of a properly grounded receptacle), you are likely starting with a grounded metal box and everything should be fine now. But the only way to tell 100% for sure, if you don't see a ground wire in the box, is to remove the box to look for conduit or an externally attached ground wire.

I see, sorry about that

With the information provided you still need to apply the sticker.
You haven't indicated that you know that any means exist to provide an approved ground. The tester would even indicate a ground by incidental contact with the neutral or with incidental with an unreliable ground, and the NEC doesn't provide any meter test to assume proper grounding.
Just put the sticker on, it won't cost you much or leave you liable.
